# Sorting Error: Hashmap<String, List<String>>

Tags: java, android, sorting, hashmap

I have a: `Hashmap<String,List<String>>` i want to sort it by `Keys` when i tried sorting it and cliked activity button my the emulator closes application. How i can fix it?
My activity inside my application look like now:

[image: ScreenShot]

I want to sort it like: 01,02,03,04,05 etc.

**Here my code blocks:**

**InsidesActivity.class:**

```
public class InsidesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    HashMap<String, List<String>> Insides_Categories;
    List<String> List_Items;
    ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    Expandible_List ExpListClass;
    Toolbar tb;
    int lastPosition = -1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_insides);
        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.explist);


            Insides_Categories = DataProvider.getInfo();
            List_Items = new ArrayList<String>(Insides_Categories.keySet());
```

I tried this block:

```
//        List<Map.Entry<String,List<String>>> entries = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String,List<String>>>(Insides_Categories.entrySet());
//        Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String,List<String>>>() {
//            public int compare(Map.Entry<String,List<String>> l1, Map.Entry<String,List<String>> l2) {
//                return l1.getValue().get(0).compareTo(l2.getValue().get(0));
//            }
//        });
```

---

```
            ExpListClass = new Expandible_List(this, Insides_Categories, List_Items);
            expandableListView.setAdapter(ExpListClass);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add your error log

Comment: @AyushKhare the IDE didnt throw an error. Just closed application when i tried join this Activity.

Comment: Maps aren't sortable.

Comment: @shmosel then what should i do? Do you have an idea for me ?

Comment: Idea for what? All you've said is that you want to sort a map, which isn't possible.

Comment: @shmosel i want to sort my ExpandibleListView like i told on top.

Comment: I don't see that you said that anywhere. Anyway, did you try searching for information? Do you think you're the first person who's tried to sort an ExpandableListView?

Comment: As i told i I've tried some solutions but didnt work.

Comment: Welcome toStack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: "didnt work" isnt something we could help with. You put up a lot of content, but it is really unclear what exactly you expect from us.

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for information i fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem when i sorted my List like this;

```
List_Items = new ArrayList<String>(Insides_Categories.keySet());
Collections.sort(List_Items);
```

**Now its looks like:**

[image: ScreenShor]

Answer (score 1):

> Use `LinkedHashMap` to maintain your sorting order. `HashMap` doesn't keep order as data inserted.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("b", Arrays.asList("1", "2"));
    map.put("a", Arrays.asList("2", "1"));
    map.put("c", Arrays.asList("2", "1", "6"));
    map.put("d", Arrays.asList("2", "1", "5"));
    Stream<Entry<String, List<String>>> sorted = map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey());
    System.out.println("map:" + map);
    map = sorted.collect(new Supplier<Map<String, List<String>>>() {

        @Override
        public Map<String, List<String>> get() {
            return new LinkedHashMap<>();
        }
    }, new BiConsumer<Map<String, List<String>>, Entry<String, List<String>>>() {

        @Override
        public void accept(Map<String, List<String>> t, Entry<String, List<String>> u) {
            t.put(u.getKey(), u.getValue());
        }
    }, new BiConsumer<Map<String, List<String>>, Map<String, List<String>>>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Map<String, List<String>> t, Map<String, List<String>> u) {
            // TODO
        }
    });
    System.out.println("map:" + map);
}
```